# how to create arcylic image of a simple image

Tags: php, css, imagemagick, gdlib

i am new on css, gdlib or image magic i have try most of example for making same image of a simple image.. but its not working

i have try php gdlib, imagemagic or css but i don't know how it will be done..

```
       .edge { width: 20px; height: 196px; background-size: auto 100%; position: absolute; left: 30px; top: 2px; transform: perspective(600px) rotateY(-45deg); transform-origin: right; }
    .panel {  position: absolute; left: 31px; top: 0; clip: rect(auto,auto,auto,20px); }
    .panel img { width: 350px; height: 200px;transform: perspective(600px)  rotateY(30deg); transform-origin: left; }

       .edgee { width: 20px; height: 196px; background-size: auto 100%;       position: absolute; left: 30px; top: 2px; transform:       perspective(600px) rotateY(-45deg); transform-origin: right; }
       .panels {  position: absolute; left: 31px; top: 0; clip: rect(auto,auto,auto,20px); }
       .panels img { width: 350px; height: 200px;transform: perspective(600px) rotateY(30deg); transform-origin: left; }
```

[image: arcylic image]

can any one guide me to design this by css, gdlib, or imagemagic..

Thanks in advance..

Comment: For ImageMagick, the [usage guide](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/distorts/#box3d) is a good start.

Comment: but how i will run it in php